Can we establish connection between Azure service to AWS service using Private Link
Can we establish connection between Azure service to AWS service using Private Link. We want to connect database hosted in Azure to a data catalog tool hosted in AWS.
We want to connect database hosted in Azure to a data catalog tool hosted in AWS. We don't want to integrate with the natove connection which directly exposes database

This might help: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/how-to-create-a-vpn-between-azure-and-aws-using-only-managed/ba-p/2281900

See also: https://www.megaport.com/blog/how-to-connect-aws-and-azure/
